# insert a column in between two arbitrary columns in a matrix

Tags: r

I want to insert a column in an existing matrix. I have written the following function:

```
> insert.col <- function(A,x,p)
    {

     cbind(x,A) -> B
     if(p == 1) return(B)

     for(i in 1:(p-1)){
     if(i == 1) B <- B[,c(i+1,i,(i+2):ncol(B))]
     else B <- B[,c(1:(i-1),i+1,i,(i+2):ncol(B))]
     }
    return(B)
    }
```

A---matrix

x---vector with compatible dimension

p---which column do you want x to appear

Example:

```
A <- matrix(1:10,nrow=2)

> A
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    3    5    7    9
[2,]    2    4    6    8   10

> insert.col(A,c(0,0),2)
       x
[1,] 1 0 3 5 7  9
[2,] 2 0 4 6 8 10

> insert.col(A,c(0,0),5)
             x
[1,] 1 3 5 7 0  9
[2,] 2 4 6 8 0 10

> str(insert.col(A,c(0,0),2))
 num [1:2, 1:6] 1 2 0 0 3 4 5 6 7 8 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr [1:6] "" "x" "" "" ...
```

I can't think of why R assign dimnames? Are there elegant ways implementing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the default of cbind is to have `deparse.level = 1` (although my understanding of what the documentation says is the opposite?), which decides labels for you based on argument names.

you can add `deparse.level = 0` to `cbind` to prevent this (I also simplified the function).

```
insert.col2 <- function(A, x, p) cbind(A[,seq_len(p-1)], x, A[,p:ncol(A)], deparse.level = 0)

insert.col2(A,c(0,0),2)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
#[1,]    1    0    3    5    7    9
#[2,]    2    0    4    6    8   10
```

Like the other 2 answers and your own function, this fails if you try to use it to add to the end of the matrix (i.e. for `p = 6` in this example).

Answer (score 2):

One possible (and simple) solution is adding `unname` function at the end of your function:  `return(unname(B))`. Running your example again gives:

```
> insert.col(A,c(0,0),2)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    1    0    3    5    7    9
[2,]    2    0    4    6    8   10
```

If you want to avoid `for` loop, you can use this version

```
append.cols <- function(A, x, p){
  if(p==1){
    B <- cbind(x, A)
  } 
  else if(p==ncol(A)){
    B <- cbind(A[,1:(p-1)], x, A[, p])
  } else {
    B <- cbind(A[,1:(p-1)], x, A[, (p+1):ncol(A)])
  }
  return(unname(B))
}
```

Examples:

```
> append.cols(A,c(0,0),2)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    0    5    7    9
[2,]    2    0    6    8   10
> append.cols(A,c(0,0),5)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    1    3    5    7    0    9
[2,]    2    4    6    8    0   10
```

Answer (score 1):

This may be simpler. Still need `unname(...)` though.

```
insert.col <- function(A,x,p)
{
  if (p==1) B <- cbind(x,A)
  else B <- cbind(A[,1:(p-1)],x,A[,p:ncol(A)])
  return(unname(B))
}

A=matrix(1:20,ncol=5)
x=rep(4,4)
insert.col(A,x,2)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
# [1,]    1    4    5    9   13   17
# [2,]    2    4    6   10   14   18
# [3,]    3    4    7   11   15   19
# [4,]    4    4    8   12   16   20
```